# In- and out-points in TextMate.app

Tags: textmate

This could be more of a Superuser question, but here goes:

I find myself deleting large amounts of text all the time, I do so by holding Shift-Arrow followed by Delete. However I would love to be able to delete in the way you edit in a video editing application, by adding in- and out-points.

You would press the "IN" keyboard shortcut where you would like the edit to begin and the "OUT" where it should end, followed by delete.

Is this crazy? Is there a way to do this in Textmate?

Comment: Well bundles are quite easy to write in textmate so if you don't find a solution then you could always throw one together

Comment: Have you seen something like this implemented in a text editor? If no, you can ask a more generalized question on SuperUser, you'll get more focus than being specific to TextMate

Comment: Sure, emacs has something similar... control-space to set the mark, move to the other end of your selection, press delete.  Not exactly the same, but similar.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor doesn't move when you use page-down or page-up, so you could just place the cursor at the beginning of the text, move the pointer to the end of the text, or page-down to where the end of the text is and move the pointer to the end, then hold the shift key down as you click after the last character you wish to delete, and all of the text between the first point and the second will be selected. Then you can hit delete. This will work in either direction (select start then end or select end then start).